Image are not displaying | building a quiz True False app with React js
Images are not displaying on a webpage and the rest is working fine! I am not getting any kind of errors, Some questions have the same images.

JSON FILE (quiz.json) I have around 1000 questions and answers with images stored in a JSON file.
[
    {
      "img": "./img_sign/550.png",
      "q": "In una carreggiata del tipo rappresentato si pu\u00f2 sorpassare anche in curva",
      "a": "true", "options": ["true", "false"]
    },
    {
      "img": "./img_sign/550.png",
      "q": "La carreggiata del tipo rappresentato \u00e8 a doppio senso di circolazione",
      "a": "true", "options": ["true", "false"]
    },
    {
      "img": "./img_sign/550.png",
      "q": "In una carreggiata extraurbana del tipo rappresentato le corsie interne sono, di norma, riservate al sorpasso",
      "a": "true", "options": ["true", "false"]
    },
    {
      "img": "./img_sign/550.png",
      "q": "In una carreggiata del tipo rappresentato non si pu\u00f2 effettuare l'inversione di marcia",
      "a": "true", "options": ["true", "false"]
    },
    {
      "img": "./img_sign/550.png",
      "q": "In una carreggiata extraurbana del tipo rappresentato si pu\u00f2 sorpassare indifferentemente sia da destra che da sinistra",
      "a": "false", "options": ["true", "false"]
    },
    {
      "img": "./img_sign/550.png",
      "q": "In una carreggiata extraurbana del tipo rappresentato si pu\u00f2 sempre marciare per file parallele",
      "a": "false", "options": ["true", "false"]
    },
    {
      "img": "./img_sign/550.png",
      "q": "In una carreggiata del tipo rappresentato possiamo iniziare un sorpasso anche se il conducente che sta dietro ha gi\u00e0 iniziato la stessa manovra",
      "a": "false", "options": ["true", "false"]
    },
    {
      "img": "./img_sign/552.png",
      "q": "Nella strada rappresentata, per ogni senso di marcia, la corsia di destra \u00e8, di norma, dedicata alla marcia ordinaria",
      "a": "true", "options": ["true", "false"]
    },
    {
      "img": "./img_sign/552.png",
      "q": "La strada rappresentata \u00e8 composta da tre corsie per ogni senso di marcia",
      "a": "true", "options": ["true", "false"]
    },
    {
      "img": "./img_sign/552.png",
      "q": "Nella strada rappresentata, per ogni senso di marcia, le corsie di centro e di sinistra sono dedicate, di norma, al sorpasso",
      "a": "true", "options": ["true", "false"]
    },
    {
      "img": "./img_sign/552.png",
      "q": "La strada rappresentata \u00e8 composta da una carreggiata",
      "a": "true", "options": ["true", "false"]
    },
    {
      "img": "./img_sign/552.png",
      "q": "Nella strada rappresentata, per ogni senso di marcia, la corsia di centro \u00e8 dedicata, di norma, alla marcia ordinaria",
      "a": "false", "options": ["true", "false"]
    },
    {
      "img": "./img_sign/552.png",
      "q": "Nella strada rappresentata, per ogni senso di marcia, la corsia di destra \u00e8 dedicata, di norma, al sorpasso",
      "a": "false", "options": ["true", "false"]
    },
    {
      "img": "./img_sign/552.png",
      "q": "La strada rappresentata \u00e8 composta da due carreggiate",
      "a": "false", "options": ["true", "false"]
    },
    {
      "img": "./img_sign/552.png",
      "q": "Nella strada rappresentata, per ogni senso di marcia, la corsia di sinistra \u00e8 dedicata, di norma, alla marcia ordinaria",
      "a": "false", "options": ["true", "false"]
    },
    {
      "img": "./img_sign/562.png",
      "q": "La strada rappresentata \u00e8 composta da tre carreggiate",
      "a": "true", "options": ["true", "false"]
    },
    {
      "img": "./img_sign/562.png",
      "q": "La strada rappresentata \u00e8 composta da otto corsie",
      "a": "true", "options": ["true", "false"]
    },
    {
      "img": "./img_sign/562.png",
      "q": "Nella strada rappresentata le carreggiate laterali sono, di norma, a senso unico",
      "a": "true", "options": ["true", "false"]
    },
    {
      "img": "./img_sign/562.png",
      "q": "Nella strada rappresentata la carreggiata centrale \u00e8, di norma, a doppio senso di circolazione",
      "a": "true", "options": ["true", "false"]
    },
    {
      "img": "./img_sign/562.png",
      "q": "La strada rappresentata consente, di norma, il sorpasso anche in curva",
      "a": "true", "options": ["true", "false"]
    },
    {
      "img": "./img_sign/562.png",
      "q": "La strada rappresentata \u00e8 composta da quattro carreggiate, tutte a senso unico",
      "a": "false", "options": ["true", "false"]
    }

]
Quiz.jsx This is my code
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import questionsData from "../components/quiz.json";
function App() {
const [questions, setQuestions] = useState([]);
const [currentQuestionIndex, setCurrentQuestionIndex] = useState(0);
const [showScore, setShowScore] = useState(false);
const [score, setScore] = useState(0);

useEffect(() => {
// Shuffle the array of questions
const shuffledQuestions = shuffleArray(questionsData);
// Slice the array to get the first 30 questions
const selectedQuestions = shuffledQuestions.slice(0, 30);
setQuestions(selectedQuestions);
}, []);

const shuffleArray = (array) => {
for (let i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
  const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
  [array[i], array[j]] = [array[j], array[i]];
}
return array;
};

const handleAnswerOptionClick = (selectedOption) => {
if (selectedOption === questions[currentQuestionIndex]?.a) {
  setScore(score + 1);
}

const nextQuestionIndex = currentQuestionIndex + 1;
if (nextQuestionIndex < questions.length) {
  setCurrentQuestionIndex(nextQuestionIndex);
} else {
  setShowScore(true);
}
};

const restartQuiz = () => {
// Shuffle the array of questions again
const shuffledQuestions = shuffleArray(questionsData);
// Slice the array to get the first 30 questions
const selectedQuestions = shuffledQuestions.slice(0, 30);
setQuestions(selectedQuestions);
setCurrentQuestionIndex(0);
setShowScore(false);
setScore(0);
};

const calculateResult = () => {
const passingScore = 27; // Set the passing score here
if (score >= passingScore) {
  return <p className="text-green-500">Congratulations! You passed.</p>;
} else {
  return <p className="text-red-500">Sorry! You failed.</p>;
}
};

return (
<div className="App bg-gray-100 min-h-screen flex justify-center items-center">
  {showScore ? (
    <div className="text-center">
      <h1 className="text-4xl font-bold mb-4">
        You scored {score} out of {questions.length}
      </h1>
      <h2 className="text-xl mb-2">
        You answered {score} questions correctly.
      </h2>
      {calculateResult()}
      <button
        className="bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded"
        onClick={restartQuiz}
      >
        Restart Quiz
      </button>
    </div>
  ) : (
    <div className="text-center">
      <h2 className="text-xl mb-2">
        Question {currentQuestionIndex + 1} of {questions.length}
      </h2>
      <h1 className="text-4xl font-bold mb-4">
        {decodeURIComponent(questions[currentQuestionIndex]?.q)}
      </h1>
      <img
        src={questions[currentQuestionIndex]?.img}
        alt="Question"
        className="max-w-full mb-4"
      />
      <div className="grid grid-cols-2 gap-4">
        {questions[currentQuestionIndex]?.options.map((option, index) => (
          <button
            key={index}
            className="bg-white hover:bg-gray-200 text-gray-800 font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded"
            onClick={() => handleAnswerOptionClick(option)}
          >
            {decodeURIComponent(option)}
          </button>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  )}
</div>
);
 }

export default App;

Any suggestions would be helpful Thank you!

How about setting the width and height for the image? You can also check via Inspect Element (F12), and see directly if the image component was rendered or not.

I have already tried setting width and height and the image in inspect mode is rendering! but not displaying

I take that as the issue has been solved?

Not yet! I can't find the problem! Any other suggestion would be helpful! thank you
